# Running a method when a module is called?

Tags: javascript

Consider this:

```
export default () => ({
    init() {
        alert('hello');
    },
});
```

Which is called via:

```
import Test from './Test';

let test = Test();
test.init();
```

Is there a way to just have a method run without having to call it? For example, could I just do:

```
import Test from './Test';

let test = Test();
```

And have something default run?

-----EDIT

I wish to have a module that can be called like:

```
import Test from './Test';

let test = Test();
```

But the module should also have various methods in it. Basically - is there some sort of constructor?

Comment: Skip the `{ init() { ... } }` wrapper around your function?

Comment: ie, `export default () => { alert('hello'); };`

Comment: Thanks @NicholasTower, but then how to I write other methods?

Comment: What other methods? If you have more requirements, please put them in your question.

Comment: @NicholasTower question has been closed unfortunately without an explanation.

Comment: [Edit] your question with more of an explanation of what you're trying to do, and we can maybe reopen it.

Comment: I have added more detail

Comment: `the module should also have various methods in it` What's the relationship between these other methods and the method you showed? If you want to export multiple unrelated or loosely related functions, you can use named exports. eg, `export const someFunction = () => {}` used like `import Test, { someFunction } from './Test'`

Comment: Module bodies are read and executed once, even if they are imported many times. It's not clear to me if you are trying to bypass this and why. If you need to import *the same instance* and need it to be initialised, then in the module create it -> initialise it -> export it. If you need *separate instances* then what is the issue with exporting function/constructor? See [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) which does a very typical import function (`const express = require('express')`) -> execute (`const app = express()`) which gives you separate instances to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default () => {
  console.log('this runs when `Test()` is called')
  return {
    init() {
      console.log('this runs when `test.init()` is called')
    }
  }
}
```